# Unable to convert varchar which is a valid isnumeric to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to convert varchar to a decimal using CAST or CONVERT. When I check if the string is a valid numeric or not, ISNUMERIC returned as valid numeric. But when CAST or CONVERT is used, it is throwing "Error converting data type varchar to numeric".

Tried different options but no luck with them. If I remove 'e+' from the string it worked but the result is not correct.

I tried to use REPLACE to see if there is anything. But no use.

```
select isnumeric( '1.67022e+006') as c,
CAST('1.67022e+006') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) AS ci,
CAST(replace('1.67022e+006','','') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) AS cii,
CAST(replace('1.67022e+006','e+','') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) AS civ,
CAST(1.67022e+006 AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) AS ciii;

CAST('1.67022e+006') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) --> Error    
CAST(replace('1.67022e+006','','') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) --> error    
CAST(replace('1.67022e+006','e+','') AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) --> 1.6702200600    
CAST(1.67022e+006 AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) --> 1670220.0000000000
```

Comment: what result is  CAST(1.67022e+006 AS DECIMAL(24, 10)) option giving you?

Comment: it is giving me result: 1670220.0000000000

Comment: And that's the right answer, check it here http://www.easysurf.cc/scintd.htm

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Decimal place moves 6  to the right. The fractional component is because you are casting to decimal (24,10)

Comment: Don't use `ISNUMERIC`; it's a bad function. Use `TRY_CONVERT` or ``TRY_CAST`.

Comment: so the fix is passing the value as number not as string via removing single quotation Ex: Use `1.67022e+006`, and don't use `'1.67022e+006'`

Comment: @Larnu: If I use TRY_CAST it is not throwing error but showing as NULL value

Comment: What error? `NULL` is valid value for a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can `CAST` exponential numbers to `decimal` directly

`CAST()` to `FLOAT` and then to `DECIMAL`

```
select  CAST(CAST('1.67022e+006' AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(24, 10))
```